# CSS: Header+main divs that size to the browser window

Tags: css

I'm looking for CSS rules to set a simple page layout.

I want a header div that has a fixed height, and extends fully across the top of the viewport from left to right,

I want a main content div that completely fills the remainder of the viewport.

There should be no area within the viewport that is not within one of these two divs, and neither div should extend beyond the viewport.

And these should remain true as I resize the browser.  Regardless of what I put in either div.  (Assuming, of course, that I'm not using overflow:visible.)

Seems simple enough, but I've not been able to make it work.

Comment: Is there a reason for the second div? why not just style the body in a way that the first div can ignore?

Comment: I want to be able to put arbitrary content in the main div, without any of it having to be aware of how tall the header div is.  I want to be able to place something at the top of the main div with "position:absolute; top:0".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/WqCYh/

For the sake of people not wanting to click the link, here's the HTML and CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #header
    {
        height:100px;
        background-color:red;
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        right:0px;
    }

    #body
    {
        background-color:blue;
        position:absolute;
        top:100px;
        left:0px;
        bottom:0px;
        right:0px;
    }
</style>

<div id="header">
    Header
</div>
<div id="body">
    Body
</div>
```

Comment: +1 This is the easiest approach with fairly little impact. I think you should add `overflow:auto` or `overflow-y:auto` to `#body` so in case there is more content it will have a scrollbar. @Hussein: The OP didn't mention explicitly that IE6 needs to be supported so I think it's fairly safe to ignore this archaic browser.

Comment: I ignore IE6 in most cases. In the cases I SHOULDN'T ignore it, I include an IE6 blocker script. :P The overflow is a good idea, yes. I though of adding it, but decided to focus squarely on getting the main layout done.

Comment: You can't ignore IE6. It's still used by many worldwide. It makes sense to use a solution that gives cross browser compatibility rather then ignoring IE6.

Comment: I know, and this isn't the place or time to discuss IE6 compatibility. Whenever possible I suggest a newer, better browser (even a newer version of IE). Many people are just uneducated in this regard, in my experience, and welcome the idea of a new browser with open arms.

Comment: In my case, IE6 compatibility is a non-issue.  We are in a position to tell our users that IE6 is not supported.  This does seem to work, for us.  At least in my simple test app.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need your content div to be the height of the browser? You can apply a background color to the body to simulate full viewport coverage.

Anyway here is the 100% height code...

CSS

```
html,body { height: 100%; }
#header { height: 100px; background: red; }
#content { min-height: 100%; background: blue; }
#inner { padding: 20px; }
```

XHTML

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="inner">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use a reset stylesheet too - [link](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) (include it before your stylesheet).

Comment: Also you'd need to have a 'position:relative' in #inner so you can bung an absolutely positioned element in there.

Comment: This will fail in IE6 and will leave a gap at the bottom in firefox and chrome

Comment: That's not working.  Or it's not doing what I want.  Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/AJdgL/ - note how the bottom absolute divs are not drawing at the bottom of the viewport.